# CakePHP3 - Standalone model for arrays/JSON data

Tags: php, json, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I retrieve JSON data from a JSON file in my CakePHP project. The application receives mainly data through JSON.

I currently have a Model (Table Model) in CakePHP, as following:

```
namespace App\Model\Table;


use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Filesystem\File;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

 class DataTable extends Table
 {

        public function getJson()
        {
            $file = new File('data.json');
            $json = $file->read(true, 'r');
            $jsonstd = json_decode($json);

            // remove STD classes
            $json2array = json_decode(json_encode($jsonstd), true);

            // return data
            return $json2array;
        }

}
```

As you can see, we still use the ORM of CakePHP while we are only retrieving data from a JSON file. How can I make a standalone CakePHP Model which is based on retrieving JSON data (without using CakePHP's ORM which purpose has database connection).

Comment: Offtopic: this double decode logic seems superflous, just decode the data to an array in the first call.

Comment: That's because I want to remove the STD classes from the array.

Comment: Yeah, and you should be able to do that with a single call by simply passing `true` for the `$assoc` argument right away in your first decode call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model is a *layer*, a *concept* and **doesn't** equal to a *table*. Obviously, you're not working with a relational databases table here you don't need it at all.

Read about the following topics, you'll find plenty of info about it on Google

- Abstraction in OOP
- MVC Design Pattern
- Separation of Concerns (SoC)

They all play into what you try to do and having understood them will make you a better programmer because your code will become better to maintain.

---

You can place any kind of class anywhere - technically. Good practice is good abstraction where it makes sense and SoC.

What you want to do is business logic and data manipulation which goes into the model layer. Pay attention to the namespace I've put it in. You could put it into `App\Model\Json` as well or wherever else you want it. I usually group my classes in namespaces / folders in a meaningful way.

```
namespace App\Model;

use Cake\Filesystem\File;

 class JsonData
 {
        public static function get($file)
        {
            $file = new File($file);
            $json = $file->read(true, 'r');
            $jsonstd = json_decode($json);

            // remove STD classes
            $json2array = json_decode(json_encode($jsonstd), true);

            // return data
            return $json2array;
        }
}

// Import the class and use it
$json = JsonData::get($file);
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I decided to group the class into `App\Model\Json`. I, however, want to call it in my controller. The `loadModel()` function of CakePHP however is not able to find the Model. How can I call a Model in a Controller by using CakePHP's functions?

Comment: Please do what the first part of my answer suggests you to do. You're mentally still stuck to the concept that a model is a class / file - **it is not**. loadModel() is a *locator* for a specific set of classes (repository classes, which table is)

Include / load your class like any other class in namespaced environment that has a class loader configured. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42836416/cakephp-loading-model-in-controller : if you have an input on my question. I have a better understanding now.