# CakePHP: Loading Model in Controller

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I would like to load my Model in my Controller. The model is not associcated with a table in the database, thus it is probably not able to follow CakePHP's ORM.

I have the following code currently (this is my Model):

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Json;

use Cake\Filesystem\File;

 class Processes
 {

        public static function getData()
        {

            $file = new File('process_data.json');
            $json = $file->read(true, 'r');

            $jsonstd = json_decode($json);

            // remove STD classes
            $json2array = json_decode(json_encode($jsonstd), true);

            $cpu = array();

            foreach ($json2array as $key => $row)
            {
                $cpu[$key] = $row['cpu_usage_precent'];
            }
            array_multisort($cpu, SORT_DESC, $json2array);
            // return data
            return $json2array;
        }
}
```

I call the Model through the following code (in the controller):

```
$json2array = $this->Processes->getJson();

$this->set('data', $json2array);
```

I am not able to call it in my Controller somehow. I keep getting the following error:

> Some of the Table objects in your application were created by
>   instantiating "Cake\ORM\Table" instead of any other specific subclass.
>
> Please try correcting the issue for the following table aliases:
>
> Processes

Comment: No a cakephp user, but i expect `AppModel` is a cakephp class related to the orm. As your class is not using the orm, dont inherent from `AppModel`

Comment: How are you calling it in your controller? If you're using `loadModel`, don't. That loads Table classes and this isn't a Table.

Comment: I don't load it through `loadModel`, but through `$this->Processes`, which is most likely not going to work since it is related to ORM.

Comment: That's something that should be in your question, as it's possibly the source of the problem. Please show exactly how and where you "load" your class.

Comment: I have updated the question with the code.

Comment: You have still not shown how and where you "load" your class. You're using `$this->Processes`; where is that member set up?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, How to access `Model` without `CakePHP ORM` in `CakePHP 3.x`

**In Model :** `Processes`

> In the file `/path_to/src/Model/Table/Processes.php`

```
namespace App\Model\Table; #Define the namespace

use Cake\Filesystem\File;

class Processes{
    public static function getData(){
       /*Your codes here*/
    }
}
```

**In Controller :** `Bookmarks`

> In the file `/path_to/src/Controller/BookmarksController.php`

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Model\Table\Processes; #Using PSR-4 Auto loading 
use App\Controller\AppController;

class BookmarksController extends AppController{
    public function tags(){
        $data = Processes::getData(); #Now you can assess Data
    }
}
```

> Here is the details about [Auto loading with PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)